# Adding a cursor to the Google map on my website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cursor

I wanted to add a map to my website. I found this easy tutorial below.
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

It worked perfectly until I realised the location I had specified in the coordinates merely centres the map, there is no actual cursor.

I googled a bit but none of the suggestions seemed to work for me. I'm hoping I just need to alter the html etc slightly.

I'm sure somebody must have done this successfully as it seems such a simple thing and the part I've already done was so easy.

Thanks.

Edit: Have fixed the link url.

Edit2: Ok here is my code at the moment:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.837004,-0.13244),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.837004,-0.13244),
      map: myMap,
      title: "BLAHBLAH PLACE"

    });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and in the body section I have:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Thanks. :S

Comment: Your links doesn't work. Could you provide your code or a fiddle?

Comment: the "map:" property needs to point to the map you created earlier, which is named "map". See here - http://jsfiddle.net/PkFJW/2/

Comment: Thank you Levi! I just changed "Mymap" to "map" and it worked. I was only two letters off this entire time! How do I vote for a fixed answer?

Ps. Thanks everyone else too. :)

Pps. I have an issue with how the map looks on mobiles. Should I make a new question for that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are interesting in adding a marker (or pin) on the map? You can add a marker to a map like so:

```
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
  map: myMap,
  title: "My pin title"
});
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) for more info on adding markers.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I had previously found that page but it doesn't seem to work. I copied and pasted in your code (changing the latlng to my own) but nothing changed. The map stick functions fine but there is no marker. I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. :( 

I have this code in the head of my html like it says to, in a script section. I think I must be doing it mainly right because my map is otherwise fine. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the console in chrome to see if any Javascript errors are being logged?